# How to style heading labels in WPF/Silverlight/XAML?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

This seems simple enough, but I'm having difficulty finding an answer.

I have a WPF window that requires use of headings and sub-headings for different areas.  Of course I could include the stlying inline for each element, but I'd really like to keep the styling separate.  What's the right way to semantically differentiate the various heading / sub-heading / "normal" label classes so that they can be properly styled in a separate XAML document?

Thanks!

Comment: You could set style manually from resources or to make a set of custom controls inheriting `TextBlock` and having different auto styles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just set styles for each of the "label classes" you want in a resource dictionary as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="heading" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="subHeading" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="normal" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

And then in your views, you would just have to call the resource and use it as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
                Source="Resources/MyResources.xaml">
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource heading}" Content="This is a heading!" />
</Grid>
```